# angularJS routing: unnecessary params in url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing

In my app if I receive password reset instructions I go to server with url like:

```
/changepass?key=1231231231212312
```

in controller I have such code:

```
  if (typeof $routeParams.key !== 'undefined') {
    $scope.changePassword();
  }
```

but when I change password and want to login in same view, I go to another location, but this `?key=123123123` is still there. What did I do wrong, and how to go to empty: /company without any keys?

```
$scope.login = function() {
        ***
                $location.path('/company');
                ***
      };
```

also I tried `$scope.$apply($location.path('/company'));`
but still when I go to company after login I have params in url. How to solve this?

In routing:

```
    .when('/signin', {
        templateUrl: 'views/authorization.html',
        controller: 'AuthorizationCtrl'
    })
    .when('/changepass', {
        templateUrl: 'views/authorization.html',
        controller: 'AuthorizationCtrl'
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways by using which you can achieve this

- `$location#url`

> $location.url($location.path('/company'));

- `$location.search`

> $location.search('key', null);

### See also

- [$location documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

---

### Not Related:

When you are using angularjs you can use its built in functions like [angular.isDefined](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isDefined)

```
if(angular.isDefined($routeParams.key)){
     $scope.changePassword();
}
```